# TextClock setTimeZone() not changing TimeZone

Tags: android, datetime

I have a TextClock in my app. I want to give the user the option of the TimeZone it displays (rather than just using the device default).

I'm using the code

```
textClock.setTimeZone("PST");
```

Which according to the API documentation should change the TimeZone of the clock to whatever the string timezone identifier is (in this case Pacific Daylight Time) but the clock isn't changing. Interestingly though it isn't showing the current time either. I'm in the UK so we are using GMT+1 and if I don't `.setTimeZone()` it shows that but if I do it shows GMT+0 regardless of the timeZone I enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that despite the documentation saying you can use three letter identifiers (or maybe I picked that up wrong), you can't.

```
textClock.setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```

That works for setting to PDT for example.

Comment: Actually you can, here's the list of available timezones https://gist.github.com/arpit/1035596

Comment: @electroid That list, while it does cover a variable for every time zone, still doesn't allow you to use standardised identifiers such as PDT. The one it lists for PDT is 'PST8PDT' which isn't an international symbol or proper notation. Still a useful link, thanks.